# Magento : getAttributeText doesn't work

Tags: php, magento

I have a dropdown attribute called "Housing" (attribute code "housing").
I want to get the text of the selected option for a product but the "getAttributeText" function returns nothing.

My code:

```
$product_object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$housing = $product_object->getHousing();
echo $housing;
echo "<br>";

$housing = $product_object->getAttributeText('housing');
echo $housing;
echo "<br>";

$housing = $product_object->getHousingText();
echo $housing;
echo "<br>";
```

The function getHousing returns the correct option id but "getAttributeText" and "getHousingText" doesn't return anything.

Any ideas why?

Comment: It's interesting that this didn't work. What is the context in which this code is run?

Comment: Agreed benmarks, if he had debugged the product object maybe there would be some useful info in there? ;) Maybe it was just a spelling error.

Comment: You must to set in admin>>attributes it attribute how "Used in Product Listing" to Yes. To see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321256/magento-getattributetextmanufacturer-doesnt-work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try,

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$housing = $prod->getResource()->getAttribute('housing')->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
echo $housing;
```

Comment: I used this code and tried to display manufacturer attribute but it gives me "No". I also set the Used in Product Listing in admin to YES

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
$product_object->getData('housing')
```

Comment: Care to comment you code, how does it works? Maybe a link to some place with a more detailed description on the `getData` uses?

Comment: Sure, here's a lengthy article about it: http://www.crearecommerce.co.uk/blog/magento-tips/getdata-method-with-products.php

Comment: @Dave your link to the article is outdated :(